# Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "\\UNC\Path" Access is denied?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm working on a proof of concept Powershell script that will be scheduled on a source host `SOURCEHOST01` and invoke commands on remote SQL servers `SQLSERV01` & `SQLSERV02`. The planned order of operations is as follows:

1. Get a SQL server hostname list from text file stored on source host 
   `\\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\SQLSERVERHOSTNAME.LIST`
2. For each SQL server, invoke a command to copy a SQL script 
   `\\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\simple_sp_who.sql` to `%TEMP%` on each SQL server.
3. `Invoke-Sqlcmd` on each SQL server using the specified SQL script.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
Get-Content \\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\SQLSERVERHOSTNAME.LIST | Foreach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        $FileSource = "\\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\"
        $FileDest = "$Env:TEMP\SQL\"
        $Database = "Master"
        $InputFile = "$FileDest\simple_sp_who.sql"
        Copy-Item $FileSource -Destination $FileDest -Recurse
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $_ -Database $Database -InputFile $InputFile 
    }
}
```

Resultant error:

```
Access is denied
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\:String) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
+ PSComputerName        : SQLSERV01
```

The script appears to be failing at Copy-Item due to file permission issues. The test environment I'm running in is running everything as Domain Admin. I'm certain it's a simple issues that I'm overlooking but I've started repeating steps so I need a fresh pair of eyes.

EDIT:

Here's what I ended up with:

```
    Get-Content \\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\SQLSERVERHOSTNAME.LIST | Foreach-Object {
            $SQLSource = Test-Path "\\$($_)\C$\Windows\Temp\SQL\"
            $FileSource = "\\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\"
            $FileDest = "\\$($_)\C$\Windows\Temp\SQL\"
    IF ($SQLSource -eq $True) {
        Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $FileDest
        Copy-Item -Recurse $FileSource $FileDest
    } ELSE {
        Copy-Item -Recurse $FileSource $FileDest
    }
            $date = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%H%M"
            $ScriptBlockContent = {
                $Database = "Master"
                $InputFile = "C:\Windows\Temp\SQL\simple_sp_who.sql"
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $_ -Database $Database -InputFile $InputFile
            }
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlockContent | Out-File -filePath "\\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\Logs\$date-$_.rpt" -NoClobber
     }
```

Seems to produce the desired results.

Comment: For future reference, you don't need to do the `$SQLSource -eq $True` test.  if the variable you are wanting to check is already a bool, you can just do `if ($SQLSource) {...}` or even `if (Test-Path "C:\path\file.txt") {...}`. Just a bit of housekeeping.... :)

Comment: Cheers @CoryKnutson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impression was wrong, but I think this is your fix. `Invoke-Command` has issues with double-hop authentication (trying to connect to the remote machine, and then connect to a network share from there). This can be fixed by using CredSSP, which has its own set of steps and security issues.

To avoid the complication and security holes of CredSSP, this  may be a fix from another perspective:

```
$Database = "Master"
$InputFile = "C:\Windows\Temp\SQL\simple_sp_who.sql"

Get-Content \\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\SQLSERVERHOSTNAME.LIST | Foreach-Object {
    Copy-Item -Path "\\SOURCEHOST01\PATH\" -Destination "\\$($_)\C$\Windows\Temp\SQL" -Recurse
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $_ -Database $Database -InputFile $InputFile 
    }
}
```

Comment: That was definitely one of the issues. I'll edit my question with what I ended up with. It's not ad 'pretty' as I want it, but it seems to work. We'll see after I schedule it and throw some actual sql scripts at it.